# Sagt man "Das Wetter ist weder schönes noch schlechtes"?

Tags: grammar

Sagt man in Deutsch

> Das Wetter ist weder schönes noch schlechtes

Comment: Proofreading questions are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified.

Comment: @Em1: this may not be the kind of "proofreading" we meant when saying it was off topic. Isn't it just a question asking for the use of a combination of adjectives to go with "weather"? We should allow such question: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/482/is-it-welcome-tolerated-to-ask-very-beginner-questions-here and maybe also http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/753/should-we-be-less-picky-on-questions-that-we-close-as-off-topic

Comment: mle: um zu vermeiden, dass deine Frage geschlossen wird solltest du uns noch kurz sagen ([edit]), wo deine Schwierigkeiten liegen. Ist es die Deklination, die üblichen Adjektive zu Wetter, oder wie man ein Gegensatzpaar bildet? Danke.

Comment: Das klingt sehr geziert. Nach dem Verb sein hat das Adjektiv normalerweise keine Endung.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Als muttersprachlicher Deutscher würde ich vorschlagen: **Das Wetter ist weder schön noch schlecht.**

*Das schöne Wetter* bzw. *schönes Wetter* wird zwar an sich gebraucht, jedoch werden die Adjektive in diesem Zusammenhang mit dem Nomen **Wetter** nicht nominalisiert.

Das Adjektiv **gut** funktioniert in diesem Kontext noch besser als *schön*, da gut das direkte Gegenteil von schlecht ist. (Danke an @Martin)

---

As a native German, I'd suggest: **Das Wetter ist weder schön noch schlecht.**

The terms *Das schöne Wetter* or *schönes Wetter* are in fact used, but these adjectives aren't nominalized in this context with the noun **Wetter**.

Note that the adjective **gut** would fit even better in this sentence, as *gut* is the direct opposite of *schlecht*. (Thanks, @Martin)

Comment: so mein satz ist nicht richtig; ist richtig dieser satz >>es ist weder schönes noch schlechtes wetter<<? Vielen Dank :)

Comment: Ja, dieser Satz ist richtig!

Comment: Man sagt normalerweise: "Wir haben heute schönes Wetter" oder "Das Wetter ist heute gut." Jedenfalls klingt "Das Wetter ist heute weder schön noch schlecht" falsch, weil "schön" und "schlecht" kein funktionierendes Gegensatzpaar sind.

Comment: Natürlich funktionieren "schön" und "schlecht" als Gegensatzpaar, aber "gutes Wetter" trifft es noch besser, das stimmt. Ich editiere meine Antwort eben.

Comment: Dann ist "hässlich" wohl auch das natürliche Gegenteil von "gut", nehme ich an ;-)

Comment: Im passenden Kontext, natürlich. Wie bei Wetter halt. "gut aussehend" <---> "hässlich"

Comment: Ich glaube nicht, dass es sich um eine versuchte Nomalisierung handelt (zumal es ja dann großgeschrieben werden müsste), sondern viel mehr OP nicht bewusst war, dass Adjektive nur in attributiver Form dekliniert werden.